# How to check existence of directory using path C#

Tags: c#, directory, exists

Using

```
Directory _dir = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

So how to store the object of directory in a variable so then I have to check whether the directory at specified path exists or not as?

```
if(!_dir.exists())
{
    _dir.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```

Is it allowed in C#?

Comment: `Directory.CreateDirectory` will actually check if the directory exists before attempting to create it, so there's really no reason to check if it exists before calling it.  However you can always use the [`DirectoryInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class, which `Directory.CreateDirectory` returns, to do what you want.

Comment: Just fyi you will always have a race condition when writing IO code like that - be ready to catch the exogenous IO exception.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Comment: @juharr it means there is no need to check whether directory exists or not because CreateDirecotory() automatically checks this. Thanks

Comment: "Is it allowed in C#?" the correct way it would be "if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path)) { System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path); }" but as @juharr mentioned, CreateDirectory already verify if it exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This...

```
        string path=@"C:\Users\v\Desktop\DESKTOP";
        if(!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryInfo dir = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
if(!dir.Exists)
{
    dir.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```

Or

```
DirectoryInfo dir = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
if(!Directory.Exists(path))
{
    dir.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```